# Flutter | I want add widget in left side how?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, textbox, alignment

[image]

im making a app using flutter how do I add a another Text widget in left side
(Im new to Flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below answer hope its helpful to you. you can used `ListTile` and `Row` **Widget** refer `ListTile` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html) and `Row` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html)

Using `ListTile`

```
ListTile(
  leading: CircleAvatar(),
  title: Text(
    'Make a word using letter  \'a\'',
  ),
),
```

Your Result Screen using ListTile ->[image: Using ListTile]

Using `Row`

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
  children: [
    CircleAvatar(),
    Text(
      'Make a word using letter  \'a\' ',
    ),
  ],
),
```

Your result screen using Row-> [image: using row]

Comment: Glad to help you. enjoy your ride with flutter

Comment: Thank you for your kindness

Answer (score 1):

> Use Row Widget.

```
  Row(  
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
  children: [
    Text('Hello Flutter'),

    const Icon(
      Icons.schedule,
      size: 18,
      color: Colors.white54,
    ),
    const SizedBox(
      width: 4,
    ),
    const Text(
      ' min',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 11,
        color:  Color(0xfff1f1f1),
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```